# toggle panels in different positions despite the same code

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

My problem is that I have two panels showing and hiding thanks to jQuery toggle() method. I'm a total noob when it comes to jQuery and I used a tutorial to make one panel, then used the same code for the second panel. In the end, the new one appears much lower than the first one and I don't know how to fix it. Also, the new panel covers almost the whole part of the website apart from the menu links that are clearly seen like on top of the panel and it shouldn't be like that. How can I fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cards div:not(:first)').hide();
    
    $('#list li').click(function(e){
        $('#cards div').hide();
        $('#list .current').removeClass("current").children().removeClass("open");
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $(this).children().addClass('open');
        
        var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
        $('#cards ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
        e.preventDefault();
    }).eq(0).addClass('current');
    
    $('.form_container').hide();
    $('button.trigger').click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
       return false;
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    background-image: url("img/wood7.jpg");
}

#container
{
    //background-color: darkorange;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#head
{
    //background-color: lightblue;
    width: 98%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#reg_welcome
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

#logo
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#login_out
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#content
{
    //background-image: url(img/sheet.png);
    //background-color: green;
    width: 95%;
    height: 700px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

/* CARDS */

#marks
{
    //background-color: lawngreen;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
}

#list
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#list li a
{
    font-size: 24px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: palegoldenrod;
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#list li a:hover
{
    opacity: 1;
}

#cards
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}

#news
{
    background-color: firebrick;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#fics
{
    background-color: indigo;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#other_stories
{
    background-color: palegoldenrod;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.open
{
    color: red;
}

/* END OF CARDS */

.categories
{
    
}

#footer
{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    width: 98%;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#author
{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 132px;
    color: goldenrod;
    font-style: italic;
}

button
{
    width: 127px;
    height: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000000, inset -3px -3px 10px #bfb6b6;
}

#log_in
{
    float: right;
}

.form_container
{
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: #ABE2F7;
    width: 90%;
}

.trigger.active
{
    background-position: right bottom;
}

input
{
    width: 88%;
    height: 18px;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #3A3A3A;
}

.submit
{
    width: 127px;
    height: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border:none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="head">
                <div id="reg_welcome">
                    <button type="button" class="trigger" id="register" onclick="showPanel">Sign up</button>
                    <div class="form_container">
                        <form action="" method="post" id="register_form">
                            E-mail: 
                            <input type="text" name="mail" /> <br />
                            Login:
                            <input type="text" name="login" /> <br />
                            Password:
                            <input type="password" name="pass" /> <br />
                            Re-type password:
                            <input type="password" name="repass" /> <br />
                            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit_log" value="Sign up" />
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="logo">
                    
                </div>
                <div id="login_out">
                    <button type="button" class="trigger" id="log_in" onclick="showPanel">Login</button>
                    <div class="form_container">
                        <form action="" method="post" id="login_form">
                            E-mail: 
                            <input type="text" name="mail_log" /> <br />
                            Password:
                            <input type="password" name="pass_log" /> <br />
                            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit_log" value="Login" />
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <div id="content">
                <div id="marks">
                    <ul id="list">
                        <li id="card_news"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                        <li id="card_fics"><a href="#fics">Fanfiction</a></li>
                        <li id="card_other"><a href="#other_stories">Other stories</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="cards">
                    <div id="news">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div id="fics">
                        <div class="categories">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="other_stories">
                        <div class="categories">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="footer">
                <span id="author">Author: </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
#log_in {
    float: right;
}
```

Because that element is floated out of the document flow, it doesn't push other elements down. Remove that, then adjust the top margin of `.form-container` to better suit:

```
.form_container {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2tx1364e/)**

Comment: Ah!! Thanks, it's much better now! Though now I'm not sure how to push that button to the right side...